# how do I compare textarea enter character

Tags: html, textarea

When I try to get the character from a textarea text it comes between quotes but when I evaluate him on console it appears like '↵'
how to compare those values?

[image: variable char]

1. variable evaluated on console
2. comparison with '↵' character
3. how it appears before evaluation

Comment: The arrow character HTML code is &#8629;  - you could use this code to compare with the arrow (to see if textarea content was an arrow)

Comment: My question is, how can I compare those values, since I compare with '↵' and its returning false.

Comment: using  &#8629;. Can I do "(char === ' &#8629;)" comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a bit of a trick to compare the values. Check for the character and replace it with the character code if found.

See snippet example:

```js
var vltest = document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML;

var newString = vltest.replace(/↵/g, '&#8629;');

alert("Old: " + vltest +  " New: " + newString); //you can comment this out, just for demo purposes to show before/after

if (newString.indexOf('&#8629;') > -1) { //check if found
  alert("Found it!")
}
```

```html
<textarea id="test1">↵</textarea>
```

The 'downward left' arrow also has codes of  `&#x21B5;` and `&crarr;` - just a piece of trivia. Feasibly you could replace the arrow with something else (other than the afore-mentioned codes), for instance a `<span>` tag or a non-breaking space, and then check for the index of it, but this way works..

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, it's helped me a lot.